# Example of Looman-Menchoff theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I would like to know of one example of a function that strictly satisfies the Loomann-Menchoff theorem.

Namely, I want a complex function $f=u+iv$, defined on some $A \subseteq \mathbb C$, such that

- $f$ is holomorphic in $A$;
- $u$ and $v$ admit partial derivatives at each point of $A$;
- $u$ and $v$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations in $A$;
- $u$ and $v$ are continuous but ***not*** differentiable at some point of $A$.

For the life of me, I can not find such an example.

Comment: The last condition isn't necessary for the Looman-Menchoff Theorem, so you're not going to find one. See the complete statement on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem. Up to technical details, we just need continuity, existence of partials, and the CR equations to get a holomorphic function. If our function is holomorphic then the real and imaginary parts are harmonic and thus smooth.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: The OP wants a function that _strictly_ satisfies the conditions of the Looman-Menchoff Theorem.  The point is that Looman-Menchoff only requires continuity, rather than differentiability, so the OP wants to see how Looman-Menchoff applies to a function which is continuous but not differentiable. \\

Stefano: Brevan Ellefsen is saying that once the conditions of Looman-Menchoff are met, then the function in question will be holomorphic, and hence $u,v$ will be smooth, and therefore differentiable in $A$.